# azure cosmos DB is not creating container under database with no errors in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

i was following this tutorial here [youtubetutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_Fi59j6BMo&t=1216s) [github](https://github.com/MarczakIO/azure4everyone-samples/tree/master/azure-cosmosdb-introduction)

**my code below(took out the key for obvious reasons)**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace azurebasics {
  public partial class App: Application {
    public App() {
      InitializeComponent();

      MainPage = new MainPage();
      CreateItem().Wait();

    }
    private static async Task CreateItem() {
      var cosmosUrl = "";
      var cosmoskey = "";
      var databaseName = "DemoDB";

      CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(cosmosUrl, cosmoskey);
      Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
      Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
        "MyContainerName", "/partitionKeyPath", 400);

      dynamic testItem = new {
        id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), partitionKeyPath = "MyTestPkValue", details = "it's working"
      };
      var response = await container.CreateItemAsync(testItem);
    }

    protected override void OnStart() {}

    protected override void OnSleep() {}

    protected override void OnResume() {}
  }
}
```

**so I would run this code and it would create the database with no container as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqAzY.png)
I'm confused because the connection works if it makes the database. and the only weird thing I found between the github and his tutorial is in the video he has**

```cs
var response = await container.CreateItemAsync(testItem);
```

**and the github has**

```cs
ItemResponse<dynamic> response = await container.CreateItemAsync(testItem);
```

Comment: `ItemResponse<dynamic>` is the data type of response. Can you please add a try-catch block to `database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync` to check if there are any exceptions.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i tried ` try {
                Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
                    "MyContainerName", "/partitionKeyPath", 400);
                dynamic testItem = new { id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), partitionKeyPath = "MyTestPkValue", details = "it's working" };
                var response = await container.CreateItemAsync(testItem);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
 };`

Comment: and I couldn't get around the scope of a try and catch block because I'm not experienced enough so I had to put all the stuff in there. also I had trouble displaying an alert from inside the try and catch block also because of scope. so I don't know how to see the exception if there is one but I did run it and nothing changed and I wasn't notified of any exceptions.

Comment: You can share the codes after adding try-catch block here and I will look into it.

Comment: I also followed the video and creating a demo, adding package, pasting code, pressing F5 to run the code, and finally I can get the same result as the video shows. So how about deleting other code you added by yourself and try again? And it's more likely that creating container method met some problems, so search for the console information may get some tips.

Comment: And, if you found that after deleting your own code in the demo, container can create successfully, try to make sure whether 'CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync' has executed, I mean that you may try 'var a = CreateItem()' instead of 'CreateItem().Wait()'

Answer (score 0):

First, please follow the [Performance Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql) and have a singleton instance of the CosmosClient. Creating a new instance every time you want to insert 1 item would be detrimental for the app.

Second, you are doing a blocking async call `CreateItem().Wait();` this can generate deadlocks. Try and execute the async operations following the recommendations on the Xamarin docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/async, for example, binding to a button that actually performs the save.